# MarkLogic HTTP Server: Set up CORS headers

Tags: ajax, cors, marklogic, web-development-server

I am running `MarkLogic 7` on a `CentOS 6.5 box`. I have my `HTML/JS` application hosted on a MarkLogic HTTP server on the same machine. The application runs on port 8003, and needs to access data through a `REST API` running on a different port 8007. When I use an `AJAX` request in my application, I get an error saying

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.16.100.104:8003' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Has anyone set up `MarkLogic` for `CORS` earlier? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:add-response-header](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aadd-response-header) to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You'll have to do that for every endpoint that needs to use cross-site requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has details.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, did you know how I could do it if I'm using MarkLogic's inbuilt REST API to access my database?

Comment: The built-in REST API endpoints don't seem to support any mechanism for adding arbitrary response headers. However you should be able to add your own headers when writing a REST extension: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions

For the built-in endpoints you might consider routing requests through another app-server layer, or a transparent reverse proxy. Either way the goal would be to re-route requests so that the browser thinks both REST API instances are on the same server.