# AngularJS connecting to MarkLogic

Tags: angularjs, marklogic

I am facing below issue while connecting to MarkLogic from AngularJS

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.:7080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Code Used to connect is as below

```
var data1=$scope.user;
alert(data1.eMail);
$http({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    data: data1,
    format: 'json'
}).success(function () {
     alert('Successfully Added In DB');
});
```

here data1 is my json object, which contains user entered information

url1 is my marklogic server path and i am trying to connect from my App http://localhost:7080/

I have even gone through couple of web sites like https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node, but due to code complexity am unable to understand clearly.
can anyone help me in giving simple steps to connect to MarkLogic from AngularJS or correct me in modifying my code written above.

I have added

xdmp.addResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); also in My MarkLogic.

Comment: Any idea how to pass dbCredentials to connect to Mark Logic from AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're facing cross origin issues.
This should be solved in the **backend** part by adding cors header to allow (or not) requests from clients.

For instance, this header : Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
would allow any requests. Normally you just want to allow known clients/ips

This has to be done in MarkLogic (which I don't know)...

Comment: As said previously, this is not a problem in AngularJS code (in client) but it has to be handled in MarkLogic(server), this answer could help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24389937/3169644

Comment: Yes Agree, but currently am lack of ideas so tried that option. Any idea how we can pass MarkLogic DB credentials to connect through AngularJS.

Comment: You must add headers, so you could use : https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_57749 . Specifically try to add header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with value "*"

Comment: Yes, i have added it but still the same issue. xdmp.addResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); not sure where am missing, i run the above in my MarkLogic but dont know hw to recheck the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header.

Comment: this header should be defined in every MarkLogic response, this is easy to see it (if well defined) in your browser debugger network pane

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to solve your CORS problem with MarkLogic's REST API:

Create a thin middle tier. [Slush](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node) is a solid reference for the 3-tier architecture which uses Node.js as a thin middle layer. [Samplestack](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack) is another example of a 3-tier solution.

Host your client assets in the same modules database as your REST API server. With this 2-tier approach, your HTTP app server is using the same port assignment, so no cross-origin issues. See @davecassel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491093/485837) for more info.

At present you can't add response headers to the built-in endpoints, you would have to create custom resource extensions.

To use built-ins, you could possibly use a transparent reverse proxy to reroute requests with Apache. See @mblakele's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271872/485837) on this.

For more details you could search SO using the [marklogic](/questions/tagged/marklogic) tag as there are other CORS-related Q&A.